# Trying to Create Chrome Extension to present entire screen in one button | Google Meet

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-meet

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that allows, with one button click to present the entire screen (instead of clicking present now, entire screen, select screen, etc) in Google Meet.

I found an issue where the "Your Entire Screen" button under "Present Now" isn't of type button in the HTML.

Code Snippet of the "Your Entire Screen" button:

`<span jsslot="" class="z80M1 FwR7Pc" jsaction="click:o6ZaF(preventDefault=true); mousedown:lAhnzb; mouseup:Osgxgf; mouseenter:SKyDAe; mouseleave:xq3APb;touchstart:jJiBRc; touchmove:kZeBdd; touchend:VfAz8(preventMouseEvents=true)" jsname="j7LFlb" aria-label="Your entire screen" role="menuitem" tabindex="0"><div class="aBBjbd MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><div class="PCdOIb Ce1Y1c" aria-hidden="true"><span class="DPvwYc giZTad" aria-hidden="true"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false" class="Hdh4hc cIGbvc NMm5M"><path d="M20 18c1.1 0 1.99-.9 1.99-2L22 6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2M4 6h16v10H4V6zm.67 13H1v2h22v-2h-3.67"></path></svg></span></div><div class="uyYuVb oJeWuf" jscontroller="o6cSOe" jsaction="JIbuQc:IGOUj" jsname="bToidb"><div class="jO7h3c">Your entire screen</div></div></span>`

How can I firstly get Javascript to be able to find this element (which I cannot currently get it to do) and secondly be able to click on this 'button'?

Comment: Is there any other element with the class name `jO7h3c`, `z80M1` or `FwR7Pc`

Comment: @Letsintegreat No

Comment: So there you go, find the element by this class name.

Comment: Ok thanks, all good!